# “Block if without end if” VBA, excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a "compare rows" code and I'm stuck with a chunk of ifs, below is the section of the code which gives me errors (the complete code is hundred-lines long, if I try to run it it gives me the error message " block if without end if", cola stores search criteria while colc(2) stores integers with the positions in a row, my question is what can I do with those lines?

```
dim cola(1 to 3) as string
dim colc(1 to 16) as string
dim rck(1 to 3) as string

If cola(1) = "Rit" Or cola(1) = "RIT" Or cola(1) = "rit" Then
    colc(4) = colc(2)
    rck(1) = "Y"
If cola(2) = "Rit" Or cola(2) = "RIT" Or cola(2) = "rit" Then
    colc(6) = colc(2)
    rck(2) = "Y"
If cola(3) = "Rit" Or cola(3) = "RIT" Or cola(3) = "rit" Then
    colc(8) = colc(2)
    rck(3) = "Y"
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing two `End If` statements:

```
dim cola(1 to 3) as string
dim colc(1 to 16) as string
dim rck(1 to 3) as string

If cola(1) = "Rit" Or cola(1) = "RIT" Or cola(1) = "rit" Then
    colc(4) = colc(2)
    rck(1) = "Y"
End If
If cola(2) = "Rit" Or cola(2) = "RIT" Or cola(2) = "rit" Then
    colc(6) = colc(2)
    rck(2) = "Y"
End If
If cola(3) = "Rit" Or cola(3) = "RIT" Or cola(3) = "rit" Then
    colc(8) = colc(2)
    rck(3) = "Y"
End If
```

or maybe you wanted the second and third `If` statements to only be evaluated if the first one was `False`, in which case you need an `ElseIf`

```
dim cola(1 to 3) as string
dim colc(1 to 16) as string
dim rck(1 to 3) as string

If cola(1) = "Rit" Or cola(1) = "RIT" Or cola(1) = "rit" Then
    colc(4) = colc(2)
    rck(1) = "Y"
ElseIf cola(2) = "Rit" Or cola(2) = "RIT" Or cola(2) = "rit" Then
    colc(6) = colc(2)
    rck(2) = "Y"
ElseIf cola(3) = "Rit" Or cola(3) = "RIT" Or cola(3) = "rit" Then
    colc(8) = colc(2)
    rck(3) = "Y"
End If
```

---

And you could possibly simplify your code by saying something like

```
If UCase(cola(1)) = "RIT" Then
```

as that will convert the value you are looking at to be all uppercase, and then you only need to check it against the uppercase version of "rit".

Answer (score 1):

In VBA, each `If` block needs an associated `End If`.

In your case, you are comparing multiple scenarios inside of one `If` block, and you will want to use `ElseIf` to accomplish this. I've added sample code below to demonstrate how this is formatted.

Here is some additional documentation on how to implement `IF-THEN-ELSE` statements in VBA:
https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_then.php

```
dim cola(1 to 3) as string
dim colc(1 to 16) as string
dim rck(1 to 3) as string

If cola(1) = "Rit" Or cola(1) = "RIT" Or cola(1) = "rit" Then
    colc(4) = colc(2)
    rck(1) = "Y"
ElseIf cola(2) = "Rit" Or cola(2) = "RIT" Or cola(2) = "rit" Then
    colc(6) = colc(2)
    rck(2) = "Y"
ElseIf cola(3) = "Rit" Or cola(3) = "RIT" Or cola(3) = "rit" Then
    colc(8) = colc(2)
    rck(3) = "Y"
End If
```